# how to find and replace sencond occurance of string using regsub

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl, trying to learn, need a help for below.
My string looks like  in configFileBuf  and trying to replace second occurance of ConfENB:local-udp-port>31001" with XYZ,  but below regsub cmd i was tried is always replacing with first occurance (37896).  Plz help how to replace second occurance with xyz.

```
set ConfigFileBuf "<ConfENB:virtual-phy>
            </ConfENB:local-ip-addr>
                    <ConfENB:local-udp-port>37896</ConfENB:local-udp-port>
            </ConfENB:local-ip-addr>
                    <ConfENB:local-udp-port>31001</ConfENB:local-udp-port>
            </ConfENB:virtual-phy>"

regsub -start 1 "</ConfENB:local-ip-addr>\[ \n\t\]+<ConfENB:local-udp-port>\[0-9 \]+</ConfENB:local-udp-port>" $ConfigFileBuf "XYZ" ConfigFileBuf
puts $ConfigFileBuf
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `regexp -indices` to find where to start the replacement, and only then `regsub`. It's not too bad if you put the regular expression in its own variable.

```
set RE "</ConfENB:local-ip-addr>\[ \n\t\]+<ConfENB:local-udp-port>\[0-9 \]+</ConfENB:local-udp-port>"
set start [lindex [regexp -all -indices -inline $RE $ConfigFileBuf] 1 0]
regsub -start $start RE $ConfigFileBuf "XYZ" ConfigFileBuf
```

The `1` is the number of submatches in the RE (zero in this case) plus 1. You can compute it with the help of `regexp -about`, giving this piece of trickiness:

```
set RE "</ConfENB:local-ip-addr>\[ \n\t\]+<ConfENB:local-udp-port>\[0-9 \]+</ConfENB:local-udp-port>"
set relen [expr {1 + [lindex [regexp -about $RE] 0]}]
set start [lindex [regexp -all -indices -inline $RE $ConfigFileBuf] $relen 0]
regsub -start $start RE $ConfigFileBuf "XYZ" ConfigFileBuf
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string was well-formed XML I'd suggest something like tDOM to manipulate it. DOM-style manipulation is almost always better than regular expression-based manipulation on XML markup. (I mention this on the off chance that it's actually supposed to be XML and you just quoted it wrong.)

It looks like you're trying to use `-start 1` to tell `regsub` to skip the first match. The starting index is actually a character index, so in this invocation `regsub` will just skip the first character in the string. You could set `-start` further into your string, but that's fragile unless you use `regexp` to calculate where the first match ends.

I think the best solution would be to get a list of indices to matches by invoking `regexp` with `-all -inline -indices`, pick out the second index pair using `lindex` and finally use `string replace` to perform the substitution, like this:

```
set pattern {</ConfENB:local-ip-addr>[ \n\t]+<ConfENB:local-udp-port>[0-9 ]+</ConfENB:local-udp-port>}
set matches [regexp -all -inline -indices -- $pattern $ConfigFileBuf]
set match [lindex $matches 1]
set ConfigFileBuf [string replace $ConfigFileBuf {*}$match XYZ]
```

The variable `match` contains a pair of indices (start and end, respectively) for the range of characters you want to replace. As `string replace` expects those indices to be in different arguments you need to expand `$match` with the `{*}` prefix. If you have an earlier version of Tcl than 8.5, you need a slight change to the above code:

```
foreach {start end} $match break
set ConfigFileBuf [string replace $ConfigFileBuf $start $end XYZ]
```

In passing, note that you can avoid escaping e.g. character sets in a regular expression if you quote it with braces instead of double quotes.

Documentation links: [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)